# Loading php features in javascript after loading page

Tags: javascript, php

I have a problem, I have a php code that loads 10 seconds. This is too long to load the page.
So I need load the whole page first without it. And on place of it show simple text "loading".
Next through javascript load and show it independently. However, these functions are 3.I need to do that with every function.
Specifically, detection of CPU / RAM / HDD state on remote servers.Because it now loads me the page for 10 seconds. This is how I would like to load whole web without this functions the first one, and after a few seconds load it, regardless of the page load.
I needed to keep these features in the same file too.
I hope you understand. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sure, sounds like you have a plan. Now go and start coding it. Then, when you fail to succeed and have a specific question, _then_ is the time to come here and ask what is wrong with your code which you then add to your question.

Comment: if detecting state of hdd cpu ram takes 10 seconds, looks like there is a problem somewhere else.

Comment: 10 seconds together. I will find pid and also uptime before it. These are game servers. And, of course, the query too. It matters a lot on the game servers type, some games can do it in 3 seconds but for example minecraft it is difficult to find pid ... so it takes me 10 seconds in a while together.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: First, make your initial page with just HTML. Then have the page make a call with AJAX to a separate PHP file which will do the more complex steps that will take time.

Answer (score 0):

Good to keep things faster from start

follow the steps
1) basic html having loading screen and divs in which other data will be placed

2) send parallel ajaxes to server to get different data in parts

3) on ajax response add data to those predefined divs

4) hide loading screen